# Can I use insert method in onCreate method?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to hardcode a single row into my SQLite database. I want to know if this will work or, if I should do something different? I want to continue using my content values, because I have so much code written with my content values.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TBL + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_HEALTH + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_RANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_INC + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_RANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_INC + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CHAR_IMG + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TOTAL_XP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP_NEEDED + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COINS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_SMALL_POTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LARGE_POTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL)"
            );
        DbHelper helper = new DbHelper();//I have to put a context in the argument 
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();//but I don't know what to put or if I'm doing it right
         values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "User1");
            values.put( KEY_LEVEL, 1);
            values.put(KEY_HEALTH, 10);
            values.put(KEY_CRIT, 5);
            values.put(KEY_CRIT_RANGE, 2);
            values.put(KEY_CRIT_INC, 2);
            values.put(KEY_HIT_RANGE, 2);
            values.put(KEY_HIT_INC, 0);
            values.put(KEY_TOTAL_XP, 0);
            values.put(KEY_XP, 0);
            values.put(KEY_XP_NEEDED, 25);
            values.put(KEY_COINS, 5);
            values.put(KEY_SMALL_POTS, 0);
            values.put(KEY_LARGE_POTS, 0);
            values.put(KEY_CHAR_IMG, 1);
            database.insert(DB_TBL,  null, values);

    }
```

logcat

```
01-04 12:36:06.403: W/dalvikvm(18454): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa3228)
01-04 12:36:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18454): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
01-04 12:36:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18454): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-04 12:36:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:77)
01-04 12:36:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.tanukiproductions.battleforchristmas.SQLiteTable$DbHelper.<init>(SQLiteTable.java:45)
01-04 12:36:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18454):    at com.tanukiproductions.battleforchristmas.SQLiteTable$DbHelper.<init>(SQLiteTable.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if this will work or, if I should do something different?

That will work, as long as `ourDatabase` references `db`. But the best way to test it is to try it yourself.

As a note, you are putting integers into text columns. While this is not an error in SQLite because of [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), it doesn't really make sense and you might have trouble when you try to sort those columns numerically. You should declare them as `INTEGER`.

Comment: Do you have to set the database to writeable before the insert method because I tried it and it isn't working

Comment: You can remove those two new lines and simply use `db.insert(DB_TBL,  null, values);`.

Comment: Understand that SQLiteOpenHelper doesn't automatically call `onCreate()` after you have previously built any database schema.

Comment: OK so I need to clear my database so it will call the onCreate method? how do i do this since ATM my app wont open?

Comment: Rather than have me guess, let's see what the real problem is. Please click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14161315/edit), then cut & paste your LogCat errors into you question.

Comment: Now I was using a `createEntry()` with the `ContentValues` and `insert()` in it and called it and that worked fine but everytime I go to the activity with `createEntry()` it will create a new row.

Comment: Simply call `createEntry()` somewhere else, like when you want to add a different user. Since you now have running code and can insert data into your database, I wish you luck! If you ever have a new problem, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22199/discussion-between-john-and-sam)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it? It should work.

Comment: I appreciate it. The reason I wanted to ask before I tried because my graphics guy is using AndEngine and that can get a bit messy. I wanted to make sure there wasnt a better way first. but awesome thank both of you guys.